# Theory of existence differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I read the definition in my text book a couple of times but still don't get how to answer questions like this:

Diff. Equation $y'+ y \ln x = \sin x$ has one and only one solution $y(x)$ where $y(\pi/2) = -1$ is this true or false, what's the logic behind it.

Comment: Look at Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The theory says that if $f(x,y)$ is continuous and locally Lipschitz in $y$ in an open set $D$, then the initial value problem $y' = f(x,y), y(x_0) = y_0$ has a unique solution defined in an interval about $x_0$ in $D$.